# Connect Elastic search with remove mysql server

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch, amazon-rds

I'm new on elastic search, i'm in a project that intent to be a system with a huge amount of data queryable, so the idea is using the elastic search to search from each index.

I try to create a system that support a cluster of elastic search, i know that we can create a cluster of ES nodes.

However me and my co-workers we're worried about data (backups, maintenance) so the idea is that ES nodes using a single instance of amazon RDS (and make amazon deal with scaling the servers) that way we can centralize the data. That is a valid thing to do?

My doubt is how I can setup the local ES server to connect with remote mysql server (RDS or other one) , i try to use https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc to make this with no success. That anyone already use ES with amazon RDS that can help?

After investigate a bit more on a plugin documentation i think that i'm understand what i'm missing.I've already configured with successful the river mode (pulling data from mysql server) however i think i'm missing the feed mode (putting data from plugin) that is why i'm not getting any data from mysql server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you point out what issue you are facing with elasticsearch-jbdc-river?

Comment: After reading the river plugin documentation i think that i already have successfully configured the river mode (since the plugin already try to pull data from mysql server) but i miss the configuration of feeder (the process of putting data on mysql node). am I right?

Comment: @Roopendra can you help one this  matter i create a new thread :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352879/connect-elastic-search-with-remove-mysql-server. Now i think i've had the river on river and feeder mode running but stll not woriking, the idea that i'm expected is adding on a remote mysql intance for each new item. i'm wrong?

Comment: Can you post your elasticsearch-jbdc-river curl command?

Comment: I think that i only run curl to activate the river not the feeder,@Roopendra can you post one sample you i can active the feeder flavor? I not seeing any command on river-jdbc github

Comment: I haven't tried feeder yet. I am familiar with river. please have a look [feeder configuration](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc#how-to-run-a-standalone-jdbc-feeder) it might give some idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that have any problems setup the river-plugin for elastic search, I've contacted the guy who maintain the plugin and he've written a step-by-step setup tutorial on linux [here](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/JDBC-plugin-feeder-mode-as-an-alternative-to-the-deprecated-Elasticsearch-River-API)

I hope that is help anyone